# How can I organize a web and a socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about node.js

Is it possible to have multiple server.js files

Like: You have one "main" server.js which routes you to another directory and there is another server.js handling socket.io or stuff like that?

To be more specific :

I want to build a Game with WebSocket's and want to have one server.js which routes you to the game page and then on the "Game Page" I want it to connect it to "another" server.js and handle stuff like websockets, login and stuff like that. Or do i have to have everything in one server.js file

I heard about the modules.export function but I don't think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: So to be clear, you want two distinct server process interacting? Or one file starting another file?

Comment: I want two server processes interact with each other

Comment: You can name it something else like init.js, app.js etc. You can name your file whatever you want not necessarily server.js, its just a name which everyone follows.I suggest you to give name of your file as per the usage of the file like socket.js

Comment: yeah i knew i can name it whatever i want, but my question is can i have one node file "connect" to another which handels someother things like sockets. An example: i have a blog with node, now i want to add a game to the blog. I make a route to the game, and then is it possible to have the game stuff (sockets) in another node file so they are not independent off one another.

Comment: Yes you can create another file for handling your sockets and other stuff.You can either run them on different ports or you can run them on same port by giving them different routes.

Comment: ok that answers my question with the routing thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are possible. If I understood right, you want to have a web server, and a socket.io server.

You can either do both in the same file:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express'),
    socket= require('socket.io'),
    app = express(),
    io = socket();

//...

app.listen(80);
io.listen(12345);
```

In different files:

web.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//...

app.listen(80);
```

io.js:

```
'use strict';
const socket= require('socket.io'),
    io = socket();

//...

io.listen(12345);
```

Comment: Thanks, Thats what i wanted to hear. One more Question if i want to make 2 Files both must be in the same folder right ?

Comment: Not neccessary, they can be different project altogether.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. You want multiple processes listening to different things. Yes you can do that. You probably want one process to listen on port 80 to handle web traffic, and the other one to listen on another port.

You can do that either by having 2 different "projects" that just share a database, or you can start 2 different servers on 2 different ports in 1 project.

If you know the responsibility of the 2 "servers" will be very different (like one server handling all the game data, etc, and the other handling standard web traffic with high scores etc.), I would probably split it out at the start.